# Can you compile Python for Android code?

Tags: android, python, compiler-construction

Is there any way to compile Python code for making Android apps or are all Android apps coded natively in Java?

Answer (score 2):

Not actually a Python compiler, but [Python for Android](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) allows you to create APKs with Python code.

About “are all Android apps coded natively in Java”: no. Android also support applications written in C, with the [Native Development Kit](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)